# I have made a counter through react.js class component but it is not incrementing i donot know what is wrong with it

Tags: reactjs, components

I do not know what is wrong with this code
I also did binding but still, it doesn't have any effect

```
<div id="root">
</div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    class Counter extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={count:0};
            this.clickHandler=this.clickHandler.bind(this);
        };

        clickHandler(){
            this.setState((prevState,props)=> {count: prevState.count+5});
            };

        render(){
            return <button onClick={this.clickHandler}> {this.state.count}</button>
        };
    };
    var element=<Counter />
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));

    </script>
```

Comment: `this.setState({count: this.state.count+5});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any error? Your click handler must be like this.

```
clickHandler() {
    this.setState((prevState,props)=> ({count: prevState.count+5}));
};
```

Check the `(` added in front of the object and `)` after it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 clickHandler() {
    this.setState(
      {
        count: this.state.count + 5
      }
    );
  }
```